# Why does the browser not render my fonts properly

Tags: webfonts

I'm using custom font with @font-face. But they're rendered with jagged edges in the browser.
I tried .woff & .otf, Chrome & Firefox; same results.

[image: Screenshot - big text]

Funny thing is, that the same font on the same page in small text, looks much much better (see screenshot 2).

[image: Screenshot - small text]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the cause of the problem:
The big text was in a `h1` element, which by default gets a `font-weight: bold`.
I had to unset it by putting `font-weight: unset`, & walla!!! looks amazing now .